# Is/Was boost::const_string part of boost?

Tags: c++, string, boost

**Question:**
As the title says: Is or was [`boost::const_string`](http://conststring.sourceforge.net/) part of boost? If it has been in the past, but no longer, why was it removed? Just because no one took care of its maintenance? Or due to design issues? Or is there a better replacement by now?

**Background**
While looking for immutable string implementations I found the linked page about `const_string`. However, I couldn't find that type in the current boost library (maybe I overlooked it). The files at the distribution point mentioned in the document (https://sourceforge.net/projects/conststring/) apparently haven't been updated since ~2005 and all other references I found where also pretty old.
Or am I completely wrong and the class was either never actually a part of boost or it is still one but I just didn't find it?

As I wrote a similar `const_string` class (albeit a c++11 / now c++17 version) I'm very interested in any lessons that could be learned from its design or that of any successor.

Comment: The download archive is dated 2005-08-04, I guess no one is maintaining it.  I can't find it in an official Boost archive perhaps it was just a proposed addition.

Comment: It never was [part of boost](http://www.boost.org/users/history/) in the first place.

Comment: You can [report](https://github.com/max0x7ba/const_string/issues) it as an issue :)

Comment: @DanMašek: I also wan't able to find it in one of the older repositories, but I was wondering if it might have been ended up as part of another boost library or if it was even older than the boost archive.

Comment: @RustyX: Thanks! I actually never realized that this repo belongs to the original author and thought it was just another copy

Comment: @MikeMB All the documentation for boost since 1.31.0 is online (and indexed by google). If it ever was there, searching for something like `site:boost.org const_string` would pick it up. The only mentions I find are a tutorial on how to use boost.test. | This certainly wouldn't be the first or last library that aspired for inclusion to boost (and has "boost" in name, uses Boost license) and never made it.

Comment: I intended it for boost, but didn't have time to go through review back then 16 years ago. I will try to freshen it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After closer inspection of the link: **It was never part of boost**.

Namespace names are just namespace names. Interestingly, to prevent this kind of spoofing, some languages/runtime environment invented "Strong Naming" (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/strong-named-assemblies)

---

This seems to have been part of a Boost Test tutorial only:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/test/doc/tutorials/const_string_test.cpp
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/test/doc/tutorials/const_string.hpp

Here's the relevant tutorial article: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/test/doc/tutorials/new_year_resolution.html

Comment: I think that const_string is a different one than the one I linked to. In fact the one in boost test look more like a `std::string_view`. But thanks for digging this up.

Comment: @MikeMB TBH I didn't look at your link. I just searched for boost mentions because the title indirectly claims it used to be part of boost! If that claim was incorrect, better edit it...

Comment: Now that I _did_ look at the link, the answer is clearly: it was never part of boost.

Comment: Well, when I wrote the question, my assumption was that it had been part of boost at some time and I was just unable to find it, but apparently I was wrong. I'll think about and edit, that doesn't invalidte the comments made so far.

Comment: Not at all. That includes my answer :)